# IOError: springData.txt

Tags: python

I have been trying to workout over hooke's law and relation between distances and forces in the spring but it gives me the following error with the following code. Please check it.

```
def getData(fname):
f = open(fname, 'r')
x = []
y = []
for line in f:
  if line[0] == '#': continue
  line = line[:-1]
  elems = line.rsplit(':')
  x.append(float(elems[0]))
  y.append(float(elems[1]))
return pylab.array(x), pylab.array(y)

distances, forces = getData('springData.txt')
pylab.scatter(distances, forces)
pylab.xlabel('Distance (Meters)')
pylab.ylabel('|Force| (Newtons)')
pylab.title('Force vs. Distance for Spring')

pylab.show()
```

The error is:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 Documents/python files/lec21.py", line 14, in <module>
distances, forces = getData('springData.txt')
Documents/python files/lec21.py", line 3, in getData
f = open(fname, 'r')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'springData.txt'
```

Comment: The error is clear enough, Python is not able to find the file in current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `'springData.txt'` as file name it means "file in current working directory with given name".

Current working directory is not directory in which program is located - it is directory in which it was run. Often (especially for small scripts) those are the same (in value, but never in meaning), but in general - they are not.

Also, you could try `'./springData.txt'` which, unfortunately, means the same thing as path without "./".

To get path of program you are running (path to "lec21.py" in your case) you may use variable `__file__` - it contains path to module in which it is used.

Also, you have some pretty cool tools for path manipulation in os.path:

`os.path.realpath(path)` - turns any relative path to absolute

`os.path.dirname(file_path)` - return path to directory in which given file is stored (e.g. `os.path.dirname("C:\x\y.txt")` will return `"C:\x"` )

`os.path.join(*args)` - joins argument so that they form path, for example `os.path.join("C:\x", "y", "z.txt")` will return `"C:\x\y\z.txt"`

Now, you can get absolute path to your springData.txt as (assuming it is in the same directory as your script):

```
os.path.realpath(
    os.path.join(
        os.path.dirname(__file__),
        "springData.txt"
    )
)
```

To learn something, check official documentation:
[CLICK](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html)